# Can you install Qt-4.6.0-wince successfully?

Tags: qt, windows-ce

I'm trying to install Qt-4.6.0-wince on XP and Vista. I read the [instructions](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/install-wince.html) and follow it to install.

However, I can't install it successfully due to some fatal errors on all of the two machines. I think the problem is that qconfig.[h cpp] files are not created automatically during the configuration.

I already report about this problem, so you can see the more information [here](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-6667). However, it is still remained as unresolved.

Anybody here who has been installed it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

@KernelJ I believe the original poster is using the correct install distro - the final product will be cross compiled from Win32 to WinCE; as is pointed out in the [Qt for Windows CE Requirements](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/requirements-wince.html).

@Brian, Unfortunately, I can't answer your original question - I have had unrelated trouble with the WinCE distribution myself and am working the issues now.  However, I can provide some help: I was able to get the Qt Everywhere 4.6 to cross compile on my Win32 (XP) host for WinCE.  I used the commercial version, but here is a link to the [Open Source Qt Everywhere 4.6 package](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.0.zip).  As is pointed out in the nokia instructions, make sure to use the Visual Studio command prompt, get your environment variables ironed out, create a custom mkspec (if you have to), and keep a close eye during the configuration for any warnings.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, there is some different output during the configuration after Perl installation. However, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Qt-4.6.0-**wince**, as is implied in the name and said explictly on the page you linked, is for **Windows CE**, **NOT** for Windows XP and Vista!!!

Nokia have released a nice software development kit for Qt which you can download [here](http://qt.nokia.com/products).  It is very impressive and powerful!

Comment: Calm down please. Did you see the page that I linked? http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-6667

Answer (score 0):

I got things running as compilable (and running on emulator) with VS 2008, so your milage may vary:

- Make sure the PATH variable points to \bin
- Open a command prompt (using the Visual Studio Command Prompt)
- Run the vcvars32.bat file (in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9\VC\bin) folder
- Cd into the qt folder
- Run this: `configure -no-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -platform win32-msvc2008 –xplatform                                    wincewm50pocket-msvc2008 -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit` (building for WINCE 5.0, and all the '-no-...' makes it build faster, removing stuff we don’t want)
- The setccepaths script provided sometimes doesn’t work. I used `checksdk.exe –script temp_script.bat`  (It creates a script, the default is for Pocket PC SDK 5)
- Run that script you just created (the `temp_script.bat` thing. It sets up environment variables.
- Run nmake

*whew*

and good luck.